# Best place to publish my Android app's Google Play statistics?

Tags: releasing-data, software

I have several Android apps, and do not consider their statistics as confidential.

On the contrary, I often share these statistics (as screenshots or CSV) on public forums, and sometimes people have interesting insights after viewing the data, for instance by pointing out that a particular version of the app triggered a sudden ratings drop with users that have a particular device. So **sharing my statistics is very useful** for me.

PROBLEM: Sharing CSV files manually is cumbersome, and few people know that they exist.

Is there a data sharing website specializing in Google Play statistics?

- Once in a while it would generate and import automatically my Google Play statistics ([using this kind of code](https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics)), so that I don't have to generate/download/upload them myself.
- It would allow anyone to download the data of any app.
- Ideally it would also provide ways to visualize the data.

Answer (score 3):

make a github repo, save your data there:
central location
versioning
social coding!!
you can upload virtually any format, including csv ->
bonus! github displays csvs in the browser!
also manually editing csvs in the browser on github is actually pretty straightforward.

you could also just upload them to google drive/docs and share/publish the data there...

Comment: It does not import automatically unfortunately... I guess my dream solution does not exist yet. If I have to opt for a generic solution, what would be the advantage of Github over more classic publication platforms like Datahub.io?

Comment: git push is the best import automagick in the world! datahub.io is an excellent solution as well!

Comment: `git push` need to be run manually. It is not automatic, and in addition I would need to manually browse Google Play's admin interface to generate and download CSV files. Every week.

Answer (score 3):

I tried publishing the statistics of one Android app on DataHub:

http://datahub.io/dataset/google-play-statistics

Findings:

- No automatic import from Google Play, which makes this no-go in the long term.
- No graphs or anything are generated from the statistics.
- CSV preview works, even though it is very limited.
- Web upload is very time-consuming, but there is an API so it is not a problem.

The two first point result from the fact that DataHub is a generic platform, not tailored to Google Play statistics.

Conclusion: I am still looking for a more adapted platform.